# How can I persist a HashMap<Entity, Entity> with JPA

Tags: jpa, hashmap, one-to-many

Hello I'm a newbie with the JPA-Framework. In my project I use JPA with EclipseLink and DerbyDB. It's all working for me fine. But then I would persist a HashMap, that's my problem.

The HashMap looks like (used in GameArea):

```
private HashMap<GameObject, ObjectContainer> gameObjects;
```

class GameArea:

```
@Entity
public class GameArea implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long OID;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private HashMap<GameObject, ObjectContainer> gameObjects;
}
```

class GameObject (the abstract object):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GameObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long OID;
...
}
```

class ObjectContainer (the composite component):

```
@Entity
public abstract class ObjectContainer extends GameObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long OID;
...
}
```

My HashMap is a lookup table for objects from GameObject to GameObject (as a ObjectContainer).

I've got an exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-163] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: This mapping's attribute class does not match the collection class.  [class java.util.Hashtable] cannot be assigned to [class java.util.HashMap].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping[gameObjects]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(GameArea --> [DatabaseTable(GAMEAREA)])
```

I don't know what it means...
I'm not sure with the "OneToMany" relation...

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not support mapping [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Interface [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) should be used instead. JPA provider is free to choose which actual implementation of Map it uses. As error message tells, EclipseLink uses [java.util.Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

If using Map instead of HashMap fits to requirements, then following solves problem:

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Map<GameObject, ObjectContainer> gameObjects;
```

If HashMap is needed, easy workaround is to provide method that convert between persistent field gameObjects and HashMap.